# What is axios.defaults.headers.post 'content-type' = 'application/json'

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I am new to react and and i am finding difficult to understand what  `axios.defaults.headers.post 'content-type' = 'application/json'` means.

I had search a lot but not find suitable answers what does it means.

Comment: so when you are posting something to the api you will be sending it as application/json

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS does it means that header remain same for all post requests

Comment: if you are not overriding it will be using the default one

Answer (score 5):

It sets global default headers. Please check [Global axios defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults)

Normally you should make a request as below:

```js
import qs from 'qs';
const data = { 'bar': 123 };
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url,
};
axios(options);
```

If most of your request will have `Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, you can set default header with:

```js
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

And you can delete headers line from your request options.

Answer (score -1):

It is basically using for fetching data from API in componentDidMount or if you using grapghQLfor fetching data then that time also you have to use 'content-type' = 'application/json' in resolver function.
'content-type' = 'application/json' that means your content must be in json format.

```
var options = {
    "url":"",
    "method": "POST",
        "headers":{
            "content-type":"application/json",
            "cache-control":'no-cache'
        },
        qs:{
            limit : limit 
            offset : offset
        }
    }
```